# repeat a track in a youtube video

Tags: android, youtube-api

I have a video for example it's 3 minutes long play in a youtubePlayerView.
I want the video to only play from 1:00 to 1:30 repeatedly. How can i do that.
I'm using Youtube Player API

```
public class StudyActivity extends YouTubeBaseActivity implements YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener{

YouTubePlayerView youTubePlayerView;
YouTubePlayer player = null;
Button btRepeat;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_study);

    addControls();
    addEvents();

}

private void addEvents() {
    btRepeat.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //do something here to repeat video
        }
    });
}

private void addControls() {
    youTubePlayerView = findViewById(R.id.youtubeView);
    player = null;
    youTubePlayerView.initialize(KEY.YOUTUBE_API_KEY,this);

    btRepeat = findViewById(R.id.btRepeate);
}

@Override
public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean b) {
    player = youTubePlayer;
    player.cueVideo(now_video.getId_video());
}

@Override
public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult youTubeInitializationResult) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Error!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

}

Comment: Seek to 1 min whenever you reach 1:30.

Comment: how do you know when you will reach 1:30

Comment: Run a background thread in the loop check current time use `player.getCurrentTimeMillis()` to find out the current time in the stream. Use `player.seekToMillis()` to seek to the desired position.